# Txpool not executing pending transactions

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, txpool

here is our geth command

```
screen geth console --rpc --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,debug,personal" --cache 8192 --allow-insecure-unlock --txpool.accountslots 4096 --txpool.accountqueue 4096 --txpool.globalqueue 4096 --txpool.globalslots 4096 --cache.database 60
```

We are sending a lot of txs in a day but we have to keep restarting our node because of stuck pending transactions. Pending transactions are not queueing. Any reason for this?

Comment: Can you enable txpool in rpc and tell how many transactions on average hang in pending? and how is the server loaded by resources?

Comment: 30+ always and it keeps rising. we need a solution. there are other issues on github about that but they are old and it seems everyone accepted the issue. the server is more than enough for any kind of node requirements. 

we thought it was nonce issue at first because. we are not using node wallet. we removed all of custom implementations, currenlty using only node wallet. but these day we have really high traffic.

we are thinking about using little light nodes for sending txs but i need to know why this issue is there

Comment: How many nodes do you have? If there are several, is there a pending queue in the all? How does a node behave if we leave the default txpool flags? On our private network, the same was observed on version geth 1.8.27 and server side load. After the transition to 1.9.12 and the increase in resources it was no longer repeated.